# Getting at ViewData.Model from spark template post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, spark-view-engine

I am trying to convert my spark views to use ViewData.Model instead of the namevaluecollection so that I can use AutoMapper to map my dto's to entities before it gets into my action method.

I can access the viewdata.model from the view, but upon posting back the data, viewdata.model is null. here is some sample code:

in my view: 
`<viewdata Message="string" model="MyDto" />
${Model.Id} < -- displays MyDto.Id`

In my filter on the server I am trying to do:
`var model = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;`

but ViewData.Model is null. This is during OnActionExecuted. Is there a trick to get the ViewData.Model to grab the values from the posted view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Spark or AutoMapper. You need to learn MVC model binders (for example [here](http://marcomagdy.com/2009/09/03/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-form-inputs-to-action-parameters/)).

```
public ActionResult Action(MyDto dto)
{
   // here dto is filled with values - automatically - if you have corresponding input fields
}
```

Comment: I got it now. I have been using asp.net mvc for awhile, and monorail before that. I just didn't know that the ViewData.Model was for output only. Previoulsy I only used the namevaluecollection dictionary for extracting data on the view